# How to call client-server side render and static generation render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to make static generation for top products with `getStaticProps`.
now a section of my rendering is not needed to static generation. for example: comments, related products.

full code:

```
export default function Gift(props) {

  let [relatedProducts, setRelatedProducts] = useState([]);

  const getRelatedProducts = () => {
    api.get(`gift/id/${props.id}/relateds/count/10`).then(res => {
      console.log(res.data.data);
      setRelatedProducts(res.data.data)
    })
  }

  //called n times. looping !!!
  getRelatedProducts();

  return (

      <GiftProvider value={props}>
        <ProductPage/>


        <RelatedProducts title="related products" products={relatedProducts}/>

        <ProductGeneralProperties/>

        <ProductComment/>

      </GiftProvider>
   
  );
}


export async function getStaticPaths() {

  const gifts = await getTopGifts()
  const paths = gifts.map((gift) => ({
    params: {slug: gift.slug}
  }))

  return {paths, fallback: 'blocking'}
}


export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const slug = context.params.slug
  const gift = await getGiftWithSlug(slug)
  return {
    props: gift,
  }
}
```

but with below code my codes renders multi times:

```
export default function Gift(props) {

  let [relatedProducts, setRelatedProducts] = useState([]);

  const getRelatedProducts = () => {
    api.get(`gift/id/${props.id}/relateds/count/10`).then(res => {
      console.log(res.data.data);
      setRelatedProducts(res.data.data)
    })
  }

  getRelatedProducts();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use useEffect hook to call the api

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getRelatedProducts = () => {
    api.get(`gift/id/${props.id}/relateds/count/10`).then(res => {
      console.log(res.data.data);
      setRelatedProducts(res.data.data)
    })
  }
getRelatedProducts();
},[])
```